# Is it possible in bash to work with a folder containing a tilde (~) and spaces?

Tags: bash, macos

In a bash script, I want to work with a value stored in the defaults system. To retrieve the value, I do:

```
defaults read my.domain my_key
#returns "~/Dropbox (My Company)/"
```

When I do the following in a bash script, the tilde (~) doesn't get expanded (I removed error handling because of brevity):

```
my_key=$(defaults read my.domain my_key)
echo $my_key
#output: "~/Dropbox (My Company)/"
```

Basically, the problem is demonstrated by this:

```
my_key='~/Dropbox (My Company)/'
echo $my_key
```

The tilde is not expanded, because the filename is between quotes (not sure if it works exactly like this). When I want to force tilde expansion, it complaints about the brackets (`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`):

```
eval my_key='~/Dropbox (My Company)/'
```

For now, I just save the full path into the defaults system (defaults write my.domain my_key -string "/Users/xxx/Dropbox (My Company)") so I don't need expansion. But I think it should work with expansion, spaces and brackets.

I'm looking for a sensible solution.

Comment: Does `/Users/xxx/` correspond to the `$HOME` value for that user?

Comment: How did the `~` get in that value? It shouldn't have been used in the first place. It is a shell-specific shortcut for a path name, and should not be used for *storing* a path name.

Comment: @Inian: yes, it is. I just didn't want to put my username here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @chepner: why can't I store `~` in a path name? If my administrator decides to re-locate the users folder, I don't want to update my settings...

Comment: Other programs beside the shell use the defaults system, and they don't necessarily know what the tilde means. `~/Dropbox (My Company)/` simply is not a valid path name by itself.

Comment: Ok, but I'm working in my own domain, so I can decide what the semantics are, right?

Comment: If your administrator moves your home directory, they can always create a symlink pointing `/Users/<me>` to your real home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if bash works differently on OS X but this seems to be the way to expand only the tilde and keep the rest quoted:

```
my_key_escaped=$(printf %q "$my_key")
eval my_key_expanded=${my_key_escaped/#\\~/~}
```

This works by first quoting everything (spaces, the tilde, dollars...) and then unquoting a leading `\~` if it's there.

Comment: +1 Though this handles correctly only the simplest form of tilde-expansion (where the tilde is not followed by a username, like in `~jsmith/bin`).

Comment: The following function will handle other forms of tilde expansion too: `expand_tilde() { local s="$(printf %q "$1")"; s="${s/\\~/'~'}"; eval echo "$s"; }`

Comment: I think you don't need the `/#\\~/~` part. When the result is escaped, it can be eval-ed, and eval is handling the ~ part.

Comment: When it is escaped, a leading `~` will have turned into `\~` -- these will be the first characters of the value of `my_key_escaped`. Then if you write `eval my_key_expanded=$my_key_escaped`, bash will expand the line to `eval my_key_expanded=\~/Dropbox (My Company)/`, `eval` will indeed unescape the string to yield `my_key_expanded=~/Dropbox (My Company)/` and the result will be executed, in this case the string starting with `~` and not `/home/username` will be stored in `my_key_expanded`. That's at least what my bash gives me when I try.

Answer (score -1):

**doesn't work correctly:** From another stack overflow question, I came around an elegant, though "hacky", answer:

```
my_key=$(cd "$my_key";pwd)
```

I thought I found a simple answer... If you want simple, don't use special characters in path names..

I leave this answer as a pointer as how not to do it.

Comment: The only problem is that it doesn't work when `my_key` contains a `~`.

Comment: Argh, you are right. I thought I found a simple answer... If you want simple, don't use special characters in path names ;-)